# Draw multiple rectangle boxes on canvas without overlapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I am trying to draw multiple(max of 6) rectangles on the canvas image without actually letting them overlap the other. How can this be done in javascript?
I cant think of a logic that can be used for this..

**Edit :**

How can i detect if a mouse click is happened inside any one of the drawn rectangles so that i can move the rectangle around the canvas again without overlapping?

Comment: Just specify the rectangles at different starting `x` and `y`s, am I right?

Comment: store width, height, x position and y position of each rectangle, when you create a new one check the created coordinates against those you already have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if a new rect will overlap any of your existing rects, you must do 3 tests:

1. Does the new rect intersect any existing rect?
2. Does the new rect fully contain any existing rect?
3. Does any existing rect fully contain the new rect?

**Here's how...**

If you have existing rectangles defined with javascript objects like this:

```
var rects=[];
rects.push({left:100,right:200,top:100,bottom:200});
```

Then you can test if a new rectangle will overlap any existing rectangle like this:

```
var newRectangle={left:50,right:25,top:50,bottom:25};

function willOverlap(newRect){

    // shortcut to the new potential rect
    var r2=newRect;

    // test if one rect is completely inside another rect
    var isInside=function(rect1,rect2){
        return(rect2.left>=rect1.left && 
        rect2.right<=rect1.right && 
        rect2.top>=rect1.top &&
        rect2.bottom<=rect1.bottom);
    }

    // test if the new rect is overlapping any existing rect
    var isOverlapping=false;
    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
        var r1=rects[i];
        //
        var isIntersecting = !(r2.left>r1.right ||
        r2.right<r1.left ||
        r2.top>r1.bottom ||
        r2.bottom<r1.top);
        //
        var isContained= isInside(r1,r2) || isInside(r2,r1);
        //
        if(isIntersecting || isContained){
            isOverlapping=true;
        }
    }
    return(isOverlapping);
}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var rects=[];
var newRect;

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;

  if(!willOverlap(newRect)){
    rects.push(newRect);
  }
  drawAll();
}

function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeStyle='green';
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var r=rects[i];
    ctx.strokeRect(r.left,r.top,r.right-r.left,r.bottom-r.top);
  }
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  newRect={
    left:Math.min(startX,mouseX),
    right:Math.max(startX,mouseX),
    top:Math.min(startY,mouseY),
    bottom:Math.max(startY,mouseY),
  }

  drawAll();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeRect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY);

}


function willOverlap(newRect){

  // shortcut to the new potential rect
  var r2=newRect;

  // test if one rect is completely inside another rect
  var isInside=function(rect1,rect2){
    return(rect2.left>=rect1.left && 
           rect2.right<=rect1.right && 
           rect2.top>=rect1.top &&
           rect2.bottom<=rect1.bottom);
  }

  // test if the new rect is overlapping any existing rect
  var isOverlapping=false;
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var r1=rects[i];
    //
    var isIntersecting = !(r2.left>r1.right ||
                           r2.right<r1.left ||
                           r2.top>r1.bottom ||
                           r2.bottom<r1.top);
    //
    var isContained= isInside(r1,r2) || isInside(r2,r1);
    //
    if(isIntersecting || isContained){
      isOverlapping=true;
    }
  }
  return(isOverlapping);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag to create a new rect.<br>New rect will be added if not overlapping.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi @Austi01101110. Thanks for your replies. 
this is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5koLdpt2/. I am not able to draw multiple rectangles nor am i able to do resize and move the boxes. The moment i click outside the drawn box disappears. I am new to front end development and canvas so not sure how i can proceed. Can you please help me with the fiddle ?

Comment: @steffi.m, I've changed by example code after seeing what you're trying to do in your fiddle. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. This works. But i am not able to resize the rects nor move them. How can i get that to work?

Comment: @steffi.m Moving and Resizing--that wasn't part of your question? Luckily, Stackoverflow has many Q&A relating to "moving" and "resizing" drawings on canvas. Quick answer: Canvas drawings are permanent (not movable or resizable) so you must clear the canvas and redraw them in their new position and at their new size.

Comment: Hi Mark. I have tried achieving the moving and resizing of the rects but i am not unable to do so .Tried seeing a few blogs too, but unable to integrate them with my code. This was one of them tht i looked into : http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m3t51jo/).

Just specify the different starting points of the rectangles in JavaScript, and then draw them:

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 20, 20);

        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of each square as a box and then interpolate the logic.

To check you think of box 1 as a point cloud then check if any of the four points of box 2 is in that point cloud.

As a note I'm a java developer but the principle is the same. Math.abs is the absolute value of x.

```
if((Math.abs(b1X - b2X) < b1Width && Math.abs(b1Y - b2Y) < b1Height) ||
   (Math.abs(b1X - (b2X + b2Width)) < b1Width && Math.abs(b1Y - b2Y) < b1Height) ||
   (Math.abs(b1X - b2X) < b1Width && Math.abs(b1Y - (b2Y + b2Height)) < b1Height) ||
  (Math.abs(b1X - (b2X + b2Width)) < b1Width && Math.abs(b1Y - (b2Y + b2Height)) < b1Height))
            return false;
```

The first line checks if point 1 on b2 is in the point cloud, 2nd line if point 2 is on point cloud, 3rd line if point 3 is on the cloud, line 4 if point 4 is on the cloud

points defined as

1-----2

|. . . . |

3-----4

As you create your squares you will have to check the newly created on to the rest of them. If it returns false to any of the squares then it is overlapping.

Comment: Also, this assumes that the shape is square (or rectangular). It can get quite a lot harder to check if they are other shapes that are not wholly right angles.